# Why Jquery UI Slider not work inside magnificpopup in iphone and safari borwser?

Tags: ios, iphone, jquery-ui, safari, magnific-popup

I try to load jQuery Ui Slider in magnific popup.

it's work fine in windows browser but is not work in ios browser..

please help me solve out this question..

Here  is Code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Slider - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="magnific-popup.css">

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
   <script src="jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(function() {
    $('.mgnpop').magnificPopup({
        type: 'inline',
        closeOnContentClick: true,
        callbacks : {
            open : function(){
               $( "#slider" ).slider();
            }
          }
    });

  });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
 <a href="#popup" class="mgnpop">click here</a>
 <div id="popup">
    <div id="slider"></div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```